# Clear all List in spinner items

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, spinner

I have try this code but one array list will be clear but second data not clear please give me solution in 1st spinner clear spinner 2 data but spinner 2 cant clear 3rd spinner data please tell me solution

my array list

```
 private ArrayList<String> students;
    private ArrayList<String> teachers;
    private ArrayList<String> CastName;
    private ArrayList<String> SubCastName;

 spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            spinnerreligiontext.setText(getNames(position));
            stst = spinnerreligiontext.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(getNames(position));
            SubCastName.clear();
            CastName.clear();


            CastName();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            aaa = getNamess(position);
            System.out.println("spin2"+getNamess(position));
            SubCastName.clear();

            SubCastName();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });  spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            aaa = getSubNamess(position);

            System.out.println("spin3"+getSubNamess(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

set adapter code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {

                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the student to array list
                students.add(json.getString("AllInOne"));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(RagistarActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, teachers));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using four array to populate the spinner you can clear it by .clear() method, so

```
students.clear();
teachers.clear();
CastName.clear();
SubCastName.clear();
```

else you can set the adapter to null at the point were you need to clear spinner items